# Cannot login to WordPress admin with manually hashed password in custom user registration in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, password-hash

I have created a custom registration page in my WordPress site for visitors to sign up. On this page I am collecting user's password and saving it after it doing a password hash, `$password_hash = wp_hash_password($password)`. But when I try to login to `wp-admin`, it says **Incorrect Password**.

Here is the code snippet I am using for saving user data:

```
function process_registration() {
   $password = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['signup_password'] );
   //Grabbing other values like firstname, lastname etc.

  $password_hash = wp_hash_password( $password );

  $user_data = array(
     //other fields...
     'user_pass' => $password_hash,
     'role' => 'contributor',
  );

  $new_user_id = wp_insert_user( $user_data );

  if( is_wp_error( $new_user_id ) ) {
    //Do some stuff
  } else {
    // Do something else
  }
}
```

However, users created from `wp-admin` panel are able to login fine. Is this not possible to collect user's password and save it with custom registration form and later use the same for login?

I am still new to WordPress.

### Update

After looking into some articles and threads I have realized that generating hashed string for even the same text will always be different, and that's why it is not being able to match the hashed password with the current one. If so, how does another user created inside WordPress admin is able to login? Is this using a different approach? If yes, what? But it not, what I am missing?

Comment: This function `sanitize_text_field()` might be the problem normally when you  dealing with `password_hash()` you don't use any other escaping mechanism/cleansing mechanism

Comment: *"I have realized that generating hashed string for even the same text will always be different, and that's why it is not being able to match the hashed password with the current one"* - As it should. You don't expect to have the same hash do you? MD5 on the other hand, will produce the same hash. Your question's a tad unclear; what is the password column's length?

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile I tried your solution but no luck.

Comment: @Fred-ii- its VARCHAR(255). According to what you said, when users are created in admin panel, do their passwords get hashed using MD5 mechanism?

Comment: Maybe you are using a difefrent hashing machenism as oppose to the admin area

Comment: OK. Well, you shouldn't sanitize passwords because that may be playing a role here where there could be characters that are getting modified, that and/or there may be a white space being introduced somewhere. Passwords such as `123'\$#--<br>` are considered to be valid.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I tried by not using sanitize_text_field as per Masivuye's suggestion. But that didn't work.

Comment: @SubrataSarkar which version of wp are u on?

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile 4.9, Multisite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function process_registration() {

    global $wpdb;
    $password_converter=wp_hash_password('tara123451');
        $user_insert_query=$wpdb->insert('wp_users', array(
        'user_login' =>'username1',
        'user_pass' =>$password_converter,
        'user_email' =>'email_id@name.com',
        ));

        $user_id = $wpdb->insert_id;
        wp_update_user(array(
        'ID' =>$user_id,
        'role' => 'contributor'
        ));
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But could please tell how this differs from my approach? I am "probably" doing the same except you have used an update while I am not using it and doing the insertion at one go. How will this solve the issue?

Comment: Whoa! It worked!! It would be great if you tell me why.

Comment: I got it!! The problem is I was creating a hashed string for the password based on user input upfront before passing it into the array. `wp_insert_user` function itself takes care of password hash and we don't have to worry about it. But in your solution, because you are inserting the data using a direct insert query you have to created the hash first :) Bottom line is `wp_insert_user` function needs a plain text password. Now my approach also works fine. Your solution actually drove me to the right direction to find out the issue. Thank you very much for helping me out!!